# Cast Modifier together with a Hair Particles system

Tags: modifiers, particles

I am using Blender version 2.93.1 on a Windows 10 PC.

I made three globes. One as a sphere and two as cubes.
The sphere and the first cube have an "earth" texture, like a globe.
The second cube is more like a polygonal globe with a lot of "extruded" areas and solid areas.

All three Objects in the same position in the room. I scaled the two cubes small and only the ball is large.
At the beginning of the animation the sphere shrinks and cube number 1 grows to the original size of the sphere.
The first cube is followed by the second at a short distance.
The first cube shrinks, making way for the second cube.
That should act like a transformation.
Now only the second cube can be seen. This has areas that are combined to form a vertex group. These in turn are the basis for a particle system (hair). They take the form of "cities" and "trees".
Now I have learned and experienced that I can animate the transformation from sphere to cube with the "Cast" modifier.
So I hidden the sphere and the first cube and applied the "Cast" modifier to cube number 2.

Now I have the problem that the "cities" and "trees" do not stick to the surface of the transformed cube and float in the air. Exactly where the surface of the cube would normally be.
How can I realize that the objects in the particle system move along with the surface changed by the "Cast" modifier?

Regards

Benjamin

Edit: Add Pictures
[image]

[image]

Comment: screenshots would help. A blend file would be perfect, so we can check it out and help you.

Comment: I like the little earth!

Comment: Have you added the modifiers in the correct order? First *Cast* (top), then *Particle System* (bottom)

Comment: Oh my God. That was the solution.
I thank you so much.
I didn't even begin to think that the order of the modifiers could have an influence.
Thank you thank you thank you.

Comment: Oh my God. It looks so nice and smooth. I am so happy.
Thaaaaank you.

Comment: You're welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

Modifiers are stacked and work from top to bottom. Because of this, the order is important.

The correct order here is

- *Cast* modifier
- *Particles System* modifier (that is automatically added from the *Particle System* in the *Physics* tab)

The *Cast* modifier uses the base mesh (cube) and deforms it into a sphere. This sphere is then taken over by the *Particle System* modifier, which puts the particles that depend on the new mesh into a spherical shape.

If the order is wrong, the modifier *Particle System* adds the particles on the cube first and the modifier *Cast* deforms the cube afterwards. But it doesn't care about the particles and doesn't touch them. So they are still in the cube shape.